# ImageMagick, gm and express.js - how to set path for convert?

Tags: express, imagemagick-convert

I think the title is pretty self explanatory: I'm trying to use gm to resize uploaded images in my express.js project. I've installed imagemagick and gm, configured everything correctly, yet it doesn't work.  I get this error:

`{ [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -resize
] code: 4, signal: null }`

I got the same error when I tried to do this in `cmd`. So, from what I've gathered, the problem is in `convert` command; Windows namely has the exact same command, but for different purposes (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214579).

When I ran the `convert.exe` from the folder that imagemagick is installed, things worked correctly.

So, what I'd like to know is, how to tell gm (or rather imagemagick?) that convert should reference (in my case) this path `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16` and not call the default Windows `convert` command?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This actually works, but you have to sign out and then sign in again in windows to accept changes which makes `convert` available.